# how to use error function in AMPL

Tags: ampl

I have to use a error function in AMPL which doesn't have one itself, so I followed [a blog post](http://benlockwood.com/2012/01/11/calculating-the-normal-cdf-in-ampl-with-shared-libraries/#comment-105) to make use of a .dll to get it done.

But when I input "display myerf(1.96)" the window gives an error "can't invoke unavailable function myerf".

I don't know how to handle this because I've already put the .dll file in the AMPL folder.
Does anyone know how to get this work?

Answer (score 1):

The error message `can't invoke unavailable function myerf` means that none of the loaded function libraries provide the `myerf` function. Most likely this is because your library is named differently and therefore hasn't been loaded automatically or it is not on the dynamic library search path. Normally AMPL loads amplfunc.dll automatically, but you can load library with any name and from any location manually using the command:

```
load path/to/amplfunc.dll;
```

where `path/to/amplfunc.dll` is a path to your function library. You can get the set of currently loaded libraries using the following command:

```
display _LIBS;
```

For more details on AMPL libraries see http://www.ampl.com/NEW/libload.html

**Update:**

Note that [AMPLGSL](https://github.com/vitaut/ampl/tree/master/solvers/amplgsl), an AMPL function library providing access to the GNU Scientific Library (GSL) functions, already has the [error function](http://ampl.github.io/amplgsl/erf.html). See the [AMPLGSL documentation](http://ampl.github.io/amplgsl/) for more details.